# IPMI only over HTTP

Tags: security, ipmi, filtering

I am actually performing a security review for a customer and I'm being confusing about the IPMI case.

If I'm correct, the protocol is flawed by design, thus directly exposing the IPMI service (udp/623) on the network to password hashes extraction.

Knowing that, is it a good mitigation to only allow IPMI over HTTP (i.e. via the web UI provided by several providers like Dell, SuperMicro etc...) ?

And as a conclusion, is that possible ?! Or should the IPMI specific port be always listening ?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: IPMI is not a secure protocol.  It assumes that the network is private.  You really shouldn't be trying to do this remotely.  I highly recommend installing another device in the network so that you can tunnel securely before being able to access anything at that level.

Comment: @tudor I know that :D As you said, the network iself is secured by design, but I want to have many account managed on the BMC, without exposing password hashes. More precisely, I want to give a restricted access to users and keep my Administrator's hash secure.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, HTTPS is possible and udp port 621 isn't necessarily required.  The current Wikipedia page says this under "Current Security Status" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface#Current_Security_Status).

> IPMI supports the use of SSL by way of HTTPS for secure communication
>   with certificates.
>
> The use of default short passwords, or "cipher 0" hacks can be easily
>   overcome with the use of a RADIUS server for Authentication,
>   Authorization, and Accounting over SSL as is typical in a datacenter
>   or any medium to large deployment. The user's RADIUS server can be
>   configured to store AAA securely in an LDAP database in a secure
>   manner using either FreeRADIUS/OpenLDAP or Microsoft Active Directory
>   and related services.
>
> ...
>
> Therefore, the prudent best practice is to disable the use of the
>   Operator and Administrator roles in LDAP/RADIUS, and only enable them
>   when needed by the LDAP/RADIUS administrator. For example, in RADIUS a
>   role can have its setting Auth-Type changed to:
>
> ```
> Auth-Type := Reject
> ```
>
> Doing so will prevent RAKP hash attacks from succeeding since the
>   username will be rejected by the RADIUS server.